# How to optimize a long running script

Tags: javascript, arrays, kendo-ui

In my application a user is able to update multiple rows of my Kendo grid. After that information gets saved in my data base i have to update the rows. But the only way i can do that is to iterate through my partitions and every row of the grid to update these records.

This causes long running script errors and takes forever. and locks up the browser. My question is; is there a way i can optimize my iteration to happen either in another thread or in the background. Or is there a quicker way i can update the records.

```
//maingrid contains 400 records
//10 partitions containing 10 rows changed by user
//100 records needing to be updated.

function updateAssignmentsInUI(partitions) {

    for (var i = 0; i < partitions.length; i++) {

        for (var j = 0; j < partitions[i].length; j++) {

            var mainGrid = $("#mainGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            $.each(mainGrid.dataSource.data(), function () {

                if (this.RowSelected === true) {

                    if (this.ID === partitions[i][j].ID) {
                        var row = mainGrid.dataSource.getByUid(this.uid);
                        row.set("Changed", "Yes");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

this loops through 10 partitions, then loops through 10 records, the looks for the record in the entire list of 400 records in the maingrid. So you can imagine how long this takes before the user gets control again.

Comment: Use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: @emed: still freezes the browser until its complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just try to change / cache your queries. I don't know this will help much but try to use your code like this

```
//maingrid contains 400 records
//10 partitions containing 10 rows changed by user
//100 records needing to be updated.

function updateAssignmentsInUI(partitions) {
    var mainGrid = $("#mainGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    $.each(mainGrid.dataSource.data(), function () {
        if (this.RowSelected === true) {
            for (var i = 0; i < partitions.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < partitions[i].length; j++) {
                    if (this.ID === partitions[i][j].ID) {
                        var row = mainGrid.dataSource.getByUid(this.uid);
                        row.set("Changed", "Yes");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This way your mainGrid will be cached and you will not query it multiple times and also wont search for data of it,  also you will not run expensive n^2 loops if row is not selected. 
Here is a working demo (simplified) : 
https://plnkr.co/edit/n3ZHmlqtoKZP4UQikw2A?p=preview

For the n^2 loops. I dont know much to optimize it, ask it for more algorithm gurus.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm dealing with such large data that i barely saw a difference on my end. but it helped.

Comment: The above code should eliminate a lot of issues, however you can try to use setTimeout for asynchronus operations for last resort. Still will need the same cpu, however you can make them work in queues